# Adding tooltip to submenu

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces, tooltip, primefaces-extensions

I am unable to see the tooltip when using it for submenu:

```
<ui:composition 
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<p:menubar styleClass="menu">  
    <p:submenu id="dye" label="dye1" >   
        <p:menuitem value="#{messages.OS_MENU}" actionListener="#{navMenuBean.actionListener}" title="#{messages.OS_TITLE}" update=":mainForm" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-star"/> 
        <p:menuitem value="#{messages.GEN_MENU}" actionListener="#{navMenuBean.actionListener}" title="#{dim_messages.GEN_TITLE}" update=":mainForm" ajax="true" icon="ui-icon-star"/>
        <p:menuitem value="#{messages.INFO_MENU}" actionListener="#{navMenuBean.actionListener}" title="#{dim_messages.INFO_TITLE}" update=":mainForm" ajax="true" icon="ui-icon-star"/>
    </p:submenu> 
    <pe:tooltip for="dye"  value="test"/>
</p:menubar>

</ui:composition>
```

I think the syntax is correct

Any advice what I am missing

Thanks

Comment: You should use `<pe:tooltip>` after end tag <p:menubar>..</p:menubar>`.

Answer (score 0):

I see the tooltip using:

```xml
  <h:form id="mainForm">
      <p:menubar styleClass="menu">  
          <p:submenu id="dye" label="dye1" >   
              <p:menuitem value="OS_MENU" update=":mainForm" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-star" />
              <p:menuitem value="GEN_MENU" update=":mainForm" ajax="true" icon="ui-icon-star" />
              <p:menuitem value="INFO_MENU" update=":mainForm" ajax="true" icon="ui-icon-star" />
          </p:submenu> 
      </p:menubar>
      <p:tooltip value="test1" for="dye" />
  </h:form>
```

Comment: You can’t see the  h:form since it’s in the main jsf the example that I add was the include , I think it’s a css issue not a jsf